# onUpdate property or event

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap-table

From this command:

```
const createRegionsEditor = (onUpdate, props) => (<RegionsEditor onUpdate={ onUpdate } {...props}/>);
```

is onUpdate of

```
    RegionsEditor onUpdate
```

refering to an event or to a props of RegionsEditor?

I found the code at:  http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#celledit   from line 93, under Custom Cell Edit

Answer (score 0):

It's type looks like a function.

It's a property regardless of it's type.

It's not a native event. So it's probably a function that gets called whenever something happens in `<RegionsEditor />`.

You'll need to look at the documentation for whatever package you are using or just look in the source code...

Comment: I found 
    updateData() {
        this.props.onUpdate(this.state.name);
    }    
but I can't see   onUpdate   definiton.